# What is $E[X]$ of $V^2$ given that $V\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am trying to compute the expected value of a function $V^2$, given that $V$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu= 0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: In general, $\text{Var}(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just $\mathbb E[V^2]$. Since $\operatorname{Var}(V)=\mathbb E[V^2] - \mathbb E[V]^2$ it follows that
$$\mathbb E[V^2] = \sigma^2. $$